# Multiple SSID On Router

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

I have the Netgear WNDR4300 router, which has a 2.4GHZ network as well as 5G network.  Would it be possible for me to have 2 SSID's on my 2.4GHZ network, one called HomeNtwk1 and the other called HomeNtwk2?

If this is possible could someone give me a guide for dummies on how to achieve such?

Comment: This entirely depends on the firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound - it is the stock firmware.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the router and a quick search does indicate that your router won't support multiple SSIDs.

This is normally a corporate level requirement for things like a guest SSID.

Here a good explanation of [how to configure one with a virtual network](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/10/02/configure-multiple-ssids-with-one-router/) if your router supports it.

Most standard home routers will come with the absolute minimal requirements for cost saving reasons (As ISPs will normally provide users with the router). You'd need to go out and buy one if you want to do something fancy like this.

Edit: I should add, you can of course configure the bands to have a separate SSID. E.G. 2.4GHz XXX1 & 5GHz XXX2. Just not multiple for the same band.

Comment: OP's asking about the same band. I.E. Configure a VLAN for a guest on the 2.4GHz band.

Comment: I posted that right as you edited your answer. He is not able to do as he is saying, but he does have the ability to create two separate networks with his router by checking the `isolation` box. Same idea, with a tab bit different implantation than he was wanting.

Comment: @DrZoo Yes, but OP seems aware of that from their post. I suspect they want to set up a guest network or create a separate gateway for testing/playing.

Comment: @AaronLayfield - Yes, I am wanting to set up a separate gateway for testing.

Comment: @user2676140 Yeah, with your router that won't be possible on the same band.